# A learner for MaxEnt models using the mlr3 package

Tags: r, mlr, mlr3, maxent

I am creating a learner for Maximum Entropy (MaxEnt) models using the `mlr3` package. I use the `maxnet` function (from the `maxnet` package) to fit MaxEnt models. Here is a link to the function: [maxnet](https://rdrr.io/cran/maxnet/man/maxnet.html).

I am testing my code. I have already solved some issues, but I don't know how to fix this one. Here is the error message:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric-alike variables
```

This leads me to two questions:

**1) How can I solve this issue ?**

**2) Will the line of code below update properly during the tuning process?**

```
param_set$values = list(regmult = 1, addsamplestobackground = TRUE, clamp = TRUE, classes = "default", response_type = "cloglog")
```

I am completely new to the mlr3 package and machine learning models in general. So, any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
LearnerClassifMaxnet = R6Class("LearnerClassifMaxnet",
                               inherit = LearnerClassif,
                               public = list(
                                 initialize = function() {
                                   
                                   ## Define the parameter set of the learner
                                   print("code 1")
                                   param_set = ps(
                                     regmult                = p_dbl(default = 1, tags = "train"),
                                     addsamplestobackground = p_lgl(default = TRUE, tags = "train"),
                                     clamp                  = p_lgl(default = TRUE, tags = "predict"),
                                     classes                = p_fct(default = "default", levels = c("default", "l", "lq", "h", "lqh", "lqhp", "lqhpt"), tags = "train"),
                                     response_type          = p_fct(default = "cloglog", levels = c("link","exponential","cloglog","logistic"), tags = "predict")
                                   )
                                   
                                   print("code 2")
                                   param_set$values = list(regmult = 1, addsamplestobackground = TRUE, clamp = TRUE, classes = "default", response_type = "cloglog")
                                   
                                   ## Initialize the learner
                                   print("code 3")
                                   super$initialize(
                                     id = "classif.maxnet",
                                     feature_types = c("logical", "integer", "numeric", "factor", "ordered"), ## feature types of predictor variables
                                     predict_types = "prob",
                                     packages = "maxnet",
                                     param_set = param_set,
                                     properties = c("weights", "twoclass"),
                                     label = "Maximum Entropy",
                                     man = "mlr3learners::mlr_learners_classif.maxnet"
                                   )
                                 }
                               ),
                               
                               ## Define the train function
                               private = list(
                                 .train = function(task) {
                                   print("code 4")
                                   pv = self$param_set$get_values(tags = "train")
                                   if ("weights" %in% task$properties) {
                                     pv$weights = task$weights$weight 
                                   }

                                   ## Build the maxnet model
                                   print("code 5")
                                   invoke(
                                     maxnet::maxnet,
                                     p = task$data(cols = task$target_names), ## response variable
                                     data = task$data(cols = task$feature_names), ## predictor variables
                                     f = maxnet.formula(p = task$data(cols = task$target_names), data = task$data(cols = task$feature_names), classes = pv$classes),
                                     regmult = pv$regmult,
                                     regfun = maxnet.default.regularization,
                                     addsamplestobackground = pv$addsamplestobackground
                                   )
                                 },
                                 
                                 ## Define the predict function
                                 .predict = function(task){
                                   print("code 6")
                                   pv = self$param_set$get_values(tags = "predict")
                                   
                                   ## Ensure the same column order in training and prediction data
                                   print("code 7")
                                   newdata = mlr3extralearners:::ordered_features(task, self)
                                   
                                   ## Compute predictions
                                   print("code 8")
                                   prob = invoke(predict, object = self$model, newdata = newdata, clamp = pv$clamp, type = pv$response_type)
                              
                                   list(prob = prob)
                                 }
                               )
)
```

Here is a reproducible example to generate the error message:

```
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3learners)
library(paradox)
library(R6)
library(mlr3misc)
library(maxnet)


    source("C:/R_functions/LearnerClassifMaxnet.R")
    data("bradypus")
    bradypus_data <- bradypus[, !(colnames(bradypus) %in% c("ecoreg"))]
    bradypus_data$presence <- as.factor(bradypus_data$presence)
    bradypus_task <- mlr3::as_task_classif(x = bradypus_data, target = "presence", positive = "1")
    ## summary(bradypus_task)
    learner_test = LearnerClassifMaxnet$new()
    learner_test$train(bradypus_task)
    p = learner_test$predict(bradypus_task)
```

Comment: You'll have to wrap the maxent learner for mlr3. There's detailed documentation on how to add a new learner at https://mlr3extralearners.mlr-org.com/articles/extending.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is it possible to integrate the existing glmnet learner in creating a learner for MaxEnt models?

Comment: Not sure what you mean -- you could certainly try to replicate what the maxent package is doing, but then you might as well use the maxent package.